# Using the colon vector in a simulink function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to calculate the interimvalues of a vector in SIMULINK.
In MATLAB the code would look like this:

(u(2:end) + u(1:end-1))./2

The SIMULINK Function Block is unable to perform this operation because of the colon Operator ":" and the documentation only refers to the Math Function Block but it is not possible to enter a custom function there...

Do you know a simple way to calculate the interimvalues as described above?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What is the _exact_ error you receive?

Comment: I was able to fix it, thank you very much for help!

Comment: How did you solve it in the end? Your answer can help others.

Comment: I solved with an embedded MATLAB Block, as you also proposed :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the help file for the Fcn block it does state:

> Also, this block does not support the colon operator (:).

so I guess that isn't going to work. You can build the expression in Simulink using Selector blocks, but probably the simplest solution is to use an Embedded MATLAB block with:

```
function y = fcn(u)
%#eml

y = (u(2:end) + u(1:end-1))./2;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your Response!